# ros2 parameter server

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

currently I'm trying to use ros2 crystal.

Now my question:

How is the feature of roscore and parameter server solved in ros2 ?

e.g.
load urdf and verify model with rviz2

Thanks for any hints

Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311186/ros2-parameter-server/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2018-12-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's intentionally no "global parameter server" in ROS 2 as all parameters are now "owned" by individual nodes.

It would be possible to create a node called the "global parameter server" which allows anyone to set parameters on it and read parameters from it. We've discussed implementing this and even providing API's in rclcpp and rclpy to make is easy to use it, but we've not had time to do that.

Specifically for the urdf and rviz2, we changed to using a topic to communicate the robot description, though there's an open pr to have an option to use a parameter and you tell rviz on which node the parameter exists (e.g. the `robot_state_publisher`), see:

https://github.com/ros2/robot_state_publisher/pull/9

And:

https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/362

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2018-12-20**:
Hello William,

many thanks for your detailed answers.

Cheers
Chrimo